# Is there a Mac equivalent for window snapping?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, windows

In Windows, you can use the Win key + arrows to snap windows to half the screen.  Is there a OSX equivalent?

I found a program that does this called [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/).  It worked well, but it was just a trial version.  It has more features than I care about and costs to much (IMO).

Are there any other programs that are free or cheaper that do the same thing?

Comment: Try using El Capitain's [split screen mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since macOS El Capitan there is native support for arranging windows side by side. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/212607/revisions) provides a lot more information on how to use the feature, and how to make it work with the keyboard.

If you want more customisation, and depending on your technical inclination, you might want to try [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com), or install something like [Mjolnir](https://github.com/sdegutis/mjolnir/releases/latest) / [HammerSpoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon)

Comment: Spectacle is exactly what I am looking for and free!

Comment: And it's open source! https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle

Comment: Of course, when OS X El Capitan is released, you will have a window snapping feature builtin within Mission Control.

Comment: The link for Mjolnir doesn't work.

Comment: @xApple thanks for pointing that out, edited the answer to provide better links.

Answer (score 4):

BetterTouchTool (blog.boastr.net) does just this. I find it very convenient to use with a trackpad: by tapping in different parts of the trackpad I can snap windows to the corresponding region of the screen, one of the most useful features of BetterTouchTool (but it has many many more, check it out!)

Edit: BetterTouchTool is no longer free

Comment: I liked better touch tool for the quick and easy snapping using the touchpad.  Until it became a paid application though.  I never used any other features so I did not see the value is paying.  Spectacle works fine, just w/o a touchpad option.

Comment: BetterTouchTool is a paid option now. You should probably edit your answer to include that.

Comment: using bettersnap with spectacle. The drag and snap is great with better snap. Keyboardshort cuts are good with spectacle